# SQL - I don't see my syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, business-objects

I am using SAP Business Objects and updated the software to the newest version **4.2 SP5 Patch 1** and now BO shows me a syntax error, also SQL Syntax Checkers online for this SQL Command:

```
SELECT
    0 AS "NULL",
    1 AS eins,
    '*' AS stern,
    convert(datetime, '1900-01-01', 102) AS datum
FROM
    D_MONAT
WHERE
    D_MONAT.MONAT_ID = 0
```

The database is a Microsoft SQL Server 2014. If I run the command against the database, everything is working fine, but with SAP Business Object, I get a syntax error.

Does anyone see where my syntax error is?

Here is the full SQL Command:

```html
SELECT DISTINCT
  D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.LAND_NAME,
  D_VB_HEUTE.NACHNAME + ', ' + D_VB_HEUTE.VORNAME,
  D_VB_HEUTE.VB_NR,
  D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.REGION_NR,
  D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.REGION_NAME,
  D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.BEZIRK_NR,
  D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.BEZIRK_NAME,
  D_BERICHTSMONAT.MONAT,
  D_BERICHTSMONAT.MONAT_NAM,
  D_VB_HEUTE.VORNAME + ' ' + D_VB_HEUTE.NACHNAME,
  D_VB_HEUTE.NACHNAME,
  D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE.BEZIRK_NR,
  D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE.VL_NAME,
  sum(VF_AUFTRAG.AE_PROV_PLANKURS)
FROM
  D_MONAT  D_BERICHTSMONAT INNER JOIN VF_AUFTRAG ON (VF_AUFTRAG.BERMONAT_ID = D_BERICHTSMONAT.MONAT_ID)
   INNER JOIN V_D_VB ON (VF_AUFTRAG.VB_ID=V_D_VB.VB_ID  AND  V_D_VB.EINTRITT_DAT <> V_D_VB.AUSTRITT_DAT)
   INNER JOIN ( 
  select d_orga.*,
  (case
    when (d_orga.LAND_SCHL <> '00' and d_orga.REGION_NR = '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'LAND'
    when (d_orga.REGION_NR <> '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'REGION'
    when (d_orga.VL_NR <> '0000000000' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'VL'
    when (d_orga.BEZIRK_NR <> '00') then 'BEZIRK'
    else 'UNBEKANNT'
   end) AS knotentyp
from d_orga
  )  D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH ON (substring(V_D_VB.KSLBEZIRK, 1, 6) = D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.BEZIRK_SCHL  AND  D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.GUELTIG_BIS = (SELECT MAX(orga.GUELTIG_BIS) FROM D_ORGA orga WHERE orga.BEZIRK_SCHL = D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.BEZIRK_SCHL))
   INNER JOIN V_D_VB  D_VB_HEUTE ON (V_D_VB.NACHF_VB_NR=D_VB_HEUTE.VB_NR and V_D_VB.NACHF_BUKRS=D_VB_HEUTE.BUKRS  AND  D_VB_HEUTE.GUELTIG_BIS = convert(date,'99991231',112))
   INNER JOIN ( 
  select d_orga.*,
  (case
    when (d_orga.LAND_SCHL <> '00' and d_orga.REGION_NR = '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'LAND'
    when (d_orga.REGION_NR <> '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'REGION'
    when (d_orga.VL_NR <> '0000000000' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'VL'
    when (d_orga.BEZIRK_NR <> '00') then 'BEZIRK'
    else 'UNBEKANNT'
   end) AS knotentyp
from d_orga
  )  D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE ON (substring(D_VB_HEUTE.KSLBEZIRK, 1, 2) = D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE.LAND_SCHL and substring(D_VB_HEUTE.KSLBEZIRK, 5, 2) = D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE.BEZIRK_NR and (substring(D_VB_HEUTE.KSLBEZIRK, 3, 2) = D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE.REGION_NR or D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE.BEZIRK_NR <> '00')  AND  D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE.GUELTIG_BIS = convert(date,'99991231',112))
   INNER JOIN ( 
  select d_orga.*,
  (case
    when (d_orga.LAND_SCHL <> '00' and d_orga.REGION_NR = '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'LAND'
    when (d_orga.REGION_NR <> '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'REGION'
    when (d_orga.VL_NR <> '0000000000' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'VL'
    when (d_orga.BEZIRK_NR <> '00') then 'BEZIRK'
    else 'UNBEKANNT'
   end) AS knotentyp
from d_orga
  )  D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE ON (substring(V_D_VB.KSLBEZIRK, 1, 2) = D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.LAND_SCHL and substring(V_D_VB.KSLBEZIRK, 5, 2) = D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.BEZIRK_NR and (substring(V_D_VB.KSLBEZIRK, 3, 2) = D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.REGION_NR or D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.BEZIRK_NR <> '00')  AND  D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.GUELTIG_BIS = convert(date,'99991231',112))
   INNER JOIN ( 
  select d_orga.*,
  (case
    when (d_orga.LAND_SCHL <> '00' and d_orga.REGION_NR = '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'LAND'
    when (d_orga.REGION_NR <> '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'REGION'
    when (d_orga.VL_NR <> '0000000000' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'VL'
    when (d_orga.BEZIRK_NR <> '00') then 'BEZIRK'
    else 'UNBEKANNT'
   end) AS knotentyp
from d_orga
  )  D_ORGA_KNOTEN ON (VF_AUFTRAG.ORGA_ID_MODIFIED=D_ORGA_KNOTEN.ORGA_ID)
   INNER JOIN ( 
  select d_orga.*,
  (case
    when (d_orga.LAND_SCHL <> '00' and d_orga.REGION_NR = '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'LAND'
    when (d_orga.REGION_NR <> '00' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'REGION'
    when (d_orga.VL_NR <> '0000000000' and d_orga.BEZIRK_NR = '00') then 'VL'
    when (d_orga.BEZIRK_NR <> '00') then 'BEZIRK'
    else 'UNBEKANNT'
   end) AS knotentyp
from d_orga
  )  D_ORGA_KNOTEN_HEUTE ON (D_ORGA_KNOTEN.LAND_SCHL = D_ORGA_KNOTEN_HEUTE.LAND_SCHL and D_ORGA_KNOTEN.BEZIRK_NR = D_ORGA_KNOTEN_HEUTE.BEZIRK_NR and (D_ORGA_KNOTEN.REGION_NR = D_ORGA_KNOTEN_HEUTE.REGION_NR or D_ORGA_KNOTEN_HEUTE.BEZIRK_NR <> '00')  AND  D_ORGA_KNOTEN_HEUTE.GUELTIG_BIS = convert(date,'99991231',112))

WHERE
  (
   ( ('*' IN @Prompt('Land? (* = alle)', 'A', 'VB Orga aktuelle Region\VB Land', multi, free) OR ( D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.LAND_NAME ) IN @Prompt('Land? (* = alle)', 'A', 'VB Orga aktuelle Region\VB Land', multi, free))  )
   AND
   ( ('*' IN @Prompt('Region Nr? (* = alle)', 'A', 'VB Orga aktuelle Region\VB Region Nr', multi, free) OR ( D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.REGION_NR ) IN @Prompt('Region Nr? (* = alle)', 'A', 'VB Orga aktuelle Region\VB Region Nr', multi, free))  )
   AND
   ( ('*' IN @Prompt('Bezirk Nr? (* = alle)', 'A', 'VB Orga historisch\VB Bezirk Nr', multi, free) OR ( D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.BEZIRK_NR ) IN @Prompt('Bezirk Nr? (* = alle)', 'A', 'VB Orga historisch\VB Bezirk Nr', multi, free))  )
   AND
   (
    D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.BEZIRK_NR  <>  '99'
    OR
    D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.LAND_NAME  <>  'Deutschland'
   )
   AND
   ( not (( D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.REGION_NR ) = '06' and ( D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.BEZIRK_NR ) = '01')  )
   AND
   ( not (( D_VB_HEUTE.VB_NR ) = 'A0C28')  )
   AND
   (
    (
     ( ( D_BERICHTSMONAT.BEGINN_DAT ) BETWEEN V_D_VB.GUELTIG_VON AND V_D_VB.GUELTIG_BIS
OR
( D_BERICHTSMONAT.ENDE_DAT ) BETWEEN V_D_VB.GUELTIG_VON AND V_D_VB.GUELTIG_BIS  )
     OR
     ( dateadd(year, -1, D_BERICHTSMONAT.BEGINN_DAT) BETWEEN V_D_VB.GUELTIG_VON AND V_D_VB.GUELTIG_BIS
OR
dateadd(year, -1, D_BERICHTSMONAT.ENDE_DAT) BETWEEN V_D_VB.GUELTIG_VON AND V_D_VB.GUELTIG_BIS  )
    )
    AND
    (
     (
      ( NOT (( V_D_VB.AUSTRITT_DAT ) IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(( V_D_VB.AUSTRITT_DAT )) <= YEAR(( D_BERICHTSMONAT.BEGINN_DAT )) - 2)  )
      AND
      ( (-1 in @variable('Berichtsjahr?') and ( D_BERICHTSMONAT.JAHR ) in (select distinct MON.JAHR from D_MONAT MON where (dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,current_timestamp),0)-1) between MON.BEGINN_DAT and MON.ENDE_DAT)) or ( D_BERICHTSMONAT.JAHR ) in @Prompt('Berichtsjahr?', 'N', 'Berichtsmonat\Berichtsjahr', multi, free)  )
      AND
      CASE WHEN YEAR(D_VB_HEUTE.AUSTRITT_DAT) <= ( D_BERICHTSMONAT.JAHR )-2 THEN 'ALT' WHEN YEAR(D_VB_HEUTE.AUSTRITT_DAT) = ( D_BERICHTSMONAT.JAHR )-1 THEN 'EX' WHEN YEAR(( D_VB_HEUTE.EINTRITT_DAT )) = ( D_BERICHTSMONAT.JAHR ) AND ( D_VB_HEUTE.EINTRITT_DAT ) <= ( D_BERICHTSMONAT.ENDE_DAT ) THEN 'N' WHEN ( D_VB_HEUTE.EINTRITT_DAT ) > ( D_BERICHTSMONAT.ENDE_DAT ) THEN 'Z' ELSE 'S' END  NOT IN  ( 'ALT'  )
     )
     OR
     convert(varchar, ( D_BERICHTSMONAT.JAHR )) + '_' + ( D_VB_HEUTE.VB_NR )   IN  @dpvalue('A', DP6.DO6a4)
    )
   )
   AND
   ( ('*' IN @Prompt('Verkaufsleiter? (* = alle)', 'A', 'Organisation\Verkaufsleiter', multi, free) OR ( D_ORGA_KNOTEN_HEUTE.VL_NAME ) IN @Prompt('Verkaufsleiter? (* = alle)', 'A', 'Organisation\Verkaufsleiter', multi, free))  )
   AND
   D_VB_HEUTE.VBART_SCHL  <>  'I'
  )
GROUP BY
  D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.LAND_NAME, 
  D_VB_HEUTE.NACHNAME + ', ' + D_VB_HEUTE.VORNAME, 
  D_VB_HEUTE.VB_NR, 
  D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.REGION_NR, 
  D_ORGA_VB_REGION_HEUTE.REGION_NAME, 
  D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.BEZIRK_NR, 
  D_ORGA_VB_HISTORISCH.BEZIRK_NAME, 
  D_BERICHTSMONAT.MONAT, 
  D_BERICHTSMONAT.MONAT_NAM, 
  D_VB_HEUTE.VORNAME + ' ' + D_VB_HEUTE.NACHNAME, 
  D_VB_HEUTE.NACHNAME, 
  D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE.BEZIRK_NR, 
  D_ORGA_VB_HEUTE.VL_NAME
```

Comment: Maybe ‘null’ instead of “NULL”. Also show something from SAP too

Comment: Try square brackets instead of quotes around the null. I'd show you but my smartphone keyboard doesn't appear to have square brackets.

Comment: I would hazard a guess it is the quotes as @SurjitSD said. But can you post the exact error if it is not?

Comment: Try to change `"NULL"` to `'NULL'` or to `[NULL]`.

Comment: The Error says "incorrect syntax near ')' but it doenst says in which line. I checked already the SAP Support Portal but the KB says also that it is a syntax error.

Comment: Also changed "NULL" to 'NULL' and [NULL] but it doesn't change anything. If i paste the SQL Command into Toad and run it, everything is fine.

Comment: If i copy the command into eversql syntax checker i get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: ''1900-01-01', 102) AS datum FROM D_MONAT WHERE D_MONAT.MONAT_ID = 0 ' at line 6

Comment: I would guess BO is adding something to the query

Comment: I've added the complete query which is created by BO in my Question. Maybe someone see whats wrong, because iam looking since hours at the command but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a syntax error. Your syntax is perfectly valid.

Initially, I though it probably has something to do with `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`, so I've decided to test:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

CREATE TABLE D_MONAT
(
    MONAT_ID int
);

INSERT INTO D_MONAT(MONAT_ID) VALUES (0), (0);

SELECT
    0 AS "NULL",
    1 AS eins,
    '*' AS stern,
    convert(datetime, '1900-01-01', 102) AS datum
FROM
    D_MONAT
WHERE
    D_MONAT.MONAT_ID = 0;


SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

SELECT
    0 AS "NULL",
    1 AS eins,
    '*' AS stern,
    convert(datetime, '1900-01-01', 102) AS datum
FROM
    D_MONAT
WHERE
    D_MONAT.MONAT_ID = 0;
```

[Both queries executed without an error](http://rextester.com/AIFHK20868), so something else is probably going on.

Try to change `"NULL"` to `'NULL'` or to `[NULL]` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I already changed "Null" to 'NULL' and [NULL]. In Sap Business Objects the Universe Design Tool says all three ways are no problem in the parsing.